# Convert this kind of char (&#x1f64f;) to emoji

Tags: php, emoji

I would like to convert this kind of character to a readable emoji

`&#x1f64f;`
=>
🙏

what PHP function should I use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [html_entity_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.html-entity-decode.php)

```
$char = html_entity_decode("&#x1f64f;");
echo $char;  //
```

or you use this unicode notation (from php 7.0)

```
echo "\u{1f64f}";  //
```